# Particle System plays at the wrong time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

I'm new to Unity and coding and am putting together a small project to help me get used to it. I have a problem with a particle system though. What I want it to do is to play two-particle systems at the same time when I hold down the spacebar and then stop when I let go, but the smoke particle system only plays after I let go of the spacebar and stops when I hold it down again. The flame particle system doesn't stop after I let go of the spacebar either. Can anyone help?

Here is the code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rocket : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float fuel = 500f;

    public float speed = 100f;

    public Rigidbody rb;

    public ParticleSystem flame;

    public ParticleSystem smoke;

    void Start()
    {
        flame.Stop();

        smoke.Stop();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && fuel > 0)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * speed);

            float fuelUse = fuel-- * Time.deltaTime;

            flame.Play();

            smoke.Play();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You are permanently restarting the particle effect..

Answer (score 0):

GetKey function resetting ur particle systems per frame so u can't see till release spacebar

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && fuel > 0)
    {

        isPressed = true;

        flame.Play();
        smoke.Play();
    }

if (isPressed && fuel > 0)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * speed);

        float fuelUse = fuel-- * Time.deltaTime;
    } 

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {

        isPressed = false;

        flame.Stop();
        smoke.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @user13145040 then please accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an **else** after your if.

In this way when you aren't pressing space it will always stop, but will start when you press space and fuel is >0.

A great thing you can do in this cases is to put some **Debug.Log()** inside the if to check when it's playing so you can find other problems.

For example you can add the else with flame.Stop() and smoke.Stop()  and put inside it a Debug.Log("stop") and inside the if a Debug.Log("play") so in the console you will always know what is happening and what is wrong

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep the debug check in mind when I get more issues like this!